# With a C# WebMethod can you show a summary or description?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

Got a question I can't seem to find any conclusive answer to. I've created a webmethod with several calls. Put summarys and descriptions on them, but when I make a reference to the live webmethod and try and call one of these methods I cannot see the description or the summary. Is there a way I can allow the end user to see instructions (in the form of a description) about what the method does?

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Something like v1 is required to be a whole number however v2, v3 etc can take -1 as a 'null' value.
/// </summary>
[WebMethod(Description="This is a description this will show a description of the method. However I cannot see it. Something like v1 is required to be a whole number however v2, v3 etc can take -1 as a 'null' value.")]
public string GetDetails(string password, int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5)
    {
            //return string based on database call etc;
    }
```

When I make a call to this method I cannot see the description or summary anywhere. Why?

Comment: Its meta data on the method that you can see if you retrieve the definition. See [How to: Use the WebMethod Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributedescription). From documentation `The Description property of the WebMethod attribute supplies a description for an XML Web service method that will appear on the Service help page.`

Comment: So what you're saying is the method stub won't ever show the description just the Service Help Page? There is no way to add some description to the method stub?